# how to check in matlab if a 3D array has at least one non zero element?

Tags: arrays, matlab, 3d

I tried to check if a 3D array is not all zeros using the next code:

```
notAll_n0_GreaterThan_ni=1;

while notAll_n0_GreaterThan_ni 
    notAll_n0_GreaterThan_ni=0;        
    mask=(n0<ni);
    numDimensions=ndims(mask);
    for dim_ind=1:numDimensions
        if any(mask,dim_ind) 
            notAll_n0_GreaterThan_ni=1;
            break;
        end
    end   
    if notAll_n0_GreaterThan_ni 
        n0(mask)=n0(mask)+1;
    end
end
```

It seems I have error in the code because at the end I get for example:       n_0(11,3,69)=21 while ni(11,3,69)=21.1556.
I can't find the error. I'll appreciate if someone shows me where I'm wrong and also if there is a simpler way to check existence of nonzero elements in a 3D array.

Comment: do you have negative values? if not just do `sum(sum(sum(data)))~=0;` If you do have negative values use  `abs(data)` as argument of the 3 sums. What is this doing... you sum up over all values (or absolut values) over your first dimension resulting in a 2d. system. Then you sum up again resulting in a 1-d array and again resulting in one digit. Which is 0 if ALL elements are zero and unequal zero otherwise. Alternatively check out `unique()` which would be a "better" solution

Answer (score 2):

Let `x` denote an *n*-dimensional array. To check if it contains at least one non-zero element, just use

```
any(x(:))
```

For example:

```
>> x = zeros(2,3,4);
>> any(x(:))
ans =
     0
>> x(1,2,2) = 5;
>> any(x(:))
ans =
     1
```

Other, more exotic possibilities include:

```
sum(abs(x(:)))>0
```

and

```
nnz(x)>0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you looking for 
`B = any(your_Array_name_here(:) ==0);` no need for loops

the (:) turns the elements of your_Array into a single column vector, so you can use this type of statement on an array of any size

I 've tested this and it works

`A = rand(3,7,5) * 5;
B = any(A(:) ==0);`

Comment: No need for `==0`, actually: `B = any(A(:));`

Comment: i leave this maybe someone looking to check array lets say ==5 or greater > 3 etc so the way     is:
`B = any(A(:) ==5);  

B = any(A(:) >3 );`